# Ensure script tag is included as first tag in the body?

Tags: javascript

I have a script file that I want third party implementors to include in their web pages.

I want this script to be the first tag included in the body, so

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my_script.js"></script>
...
```

What's the best way to go about doing this without using any third party libraries?

My intent is that this script gets run before any of the page is rendered. If the tag isn't included correctly, I want to display an error message to the developer, telling them to put the tag as the first tag in the body.

EDIT: This script is going to be used to protect against clickjacking, and will basically hide the entire document if the embedder isn't in a whitelist. Why does it need to be the first script in the page? To ensure that nothing clickable becomes visible before the script is run, and to ensure that other script errors don't interfere with this being run as well. So it doesn't absolutely need to be first, but it should be super close to first ;-) This approach is [based off of this suggestions at the Owasp site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Best-for-now_Legacy_Browser_Frame_Breaking_Script), but is trying to be a more of a "just drop it in" solution.

Comment: my first guess is, in your js, count the children of the body tag and expect 1

Comment: Iterate through the DOM and find the script tags. Ensure your tag is the first one. Seems like a bad idea though, what if I have something I need to run before your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First element in body

In `/my_script.js`. You can add this code:

```
if (document.body.firstElementChild == document.currentScript) {
    // Is first element
} else {
    // Is not first element
}
```

I'm not sure *why* you'd need to do that but here's how to do that.

## Move script to first element

If you want to move the script:

```
document.body.insertBefore(document.currentScript, document.body.firstChid);
document.currentScript.parentElement.removeChild(document.currentScript);
```

## Check if script is first script

```
if (( document.scripts || document.getElementById('script') )[0] == document.currentScript)
```

Comment: In case `document.currentScript` is not available (Internet Explorer), you can use `var currentScript = document.currentScript || function ( ) { var s = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' ); return s[s.length - 1]; }();`

Answer (score 1):

While I'm having some trouble imagining what requirement would drive you to NEED to be the FIRST tag after body, I'll set that aside for a moment to answer your technical question. Querying `document.body.childNodes` will give you the nodes loaded thusfar. You can use that information to determine if you are first in the line.

Answer (score -1):

> $(document).on("pagecreate",function(){ //do your loading stuff }

this will trigger event before the page gets rendered.

references : http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_pagecreate.asp

Comment: He didn't mention using jQuery (or other frameworks that would provide a $). Additionally, unless jQuery were loaded in <head> (not currently best practice) it wouldn't be available at the time his script is wanting to be run.